# Bash one-liner: check if a directory exists; if so, delete it, then create it anyway

Tags: bash, mkdir, rm, one-liner

I have to use `bash -c`, so i need something like `bash -c "rm -r tmp/mydir1 && mkdir -p tmp/mydir1/mydir2"`
but it does not work in this way.

Comment: What do you mean, "it does not work"? What happens?

Comment: If you don't care whether or not `rm` fails, don't us `&&`.   You should probably use `-f`.

Comment: `sh -c '[ -d "$0" ]&&rm -r "$0";mkdir -p "$0"' tmp/mydir1/mydir2`

Comment: How about `||` instead of `&&`?

Comment: @chepner, i get this message:  rm: missing operand

Comment: So when i use ```bash -c "rm -r ${tar_dir}"```  then i get: rm missing operand. But for some reason, when i use ```bash -c "true && rm -r ${tar_dir}"  ``` then it works, but only if the directory already exists. if i use ```bash -c "if [ -d "${tar_dir}" ]; then rm -r ${tar_dir}; fi"``` then i get: syntax error near unexpected token `then'

Comment: Your first error means `tar_dir` isn't defined. Your question doesn't actually reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps

```bash
bash -c "[[ -d /tmp/"${0}" ]] && { rm -r /tmp/${0}; mkdir -p /tmp/${0}; } || { mkdir -p /tmp/${0}; }"
```

Keep in mind that if you're trying to access the temporary landing place (`/tmp`) in Unix, you need to add a '/' to the start since tmp is located in the root of the file system. Otherwise, if your current project has a folder called tmp, don't worry about it.

Use the `-d` operator in bash to check if a file exists and is a directory (folder). It will check in `/tmp/` for `${0}` (Note: Change `${0}` to whatever you want to look for. Otherwise it will just look for itself).

```bash
[[ -d /tmp/${0} ]] && {
    # If a match is found (&& just mean's AND) then do whatever is placed in the {}'s, all lines in these brackets need to finish with a ';' to tell bash when it's a new line.
    rm -r /tmp/${0};
    mkdir -p /tmp/${0};
} || {
    # If there is no match (|| mean's OR)
    mkdir -p /tmp/${0};
}
```

#### Please don't forget to change ${0} the variable or the name of the folder you wish to change!

And just for future reference, here's a version of it as a function.

```bash
function FindRemoveAdd() {
    local folder="${1}"
    if [[ -d "${folder}" ]]; then
        rm -r /tmp/${folder}
        mkdir -p /tmp/${folder}
    else
        mkdir -p /tmp/${folder}
    fi
}

# Just run it by using
FindRemoveAdd "<name of folder>"
```